# Regexp Mystery in Postfix / My Mistake

Tags: regular-expression, postfix

I have these two regexp rules set up in Postfix:

```
/^From:(.*)noreply\@glassdoor\.\<com\>/ OK
```

and this one:

```
/^Message-ID:.*\.sendgrid\.net\>/  REJECT Your spam takes a hike!
```

Now its well known that it all works in sequence, that is the first rule matched triggers and then it is supposed to stop and won't process anything any further.
Now the message has the following headers:

```
From: noreply@glassdoor.com
Message-ID: <eKQ@ismtpd0003p1iad1.sendgrid.net>
```

However, it reads only the second rule and rejects the email as if the first rule does not exist at all. Why?

The regexp rules are verified by the following command that says that there are no mistakes / errors in rules themselves:

```
postmap -q "From: noreply@glassdoor.com" regexp:/etc/postfix/spam
postmap -q "Message-ID: <eKQ@ismtpd0003p1iad1.sendgrid.net>" regexp:/etc/postfix/spam
```

The task here is to accept mail when it comes from noreply@glassdoor.com but to reject it when it has .sendgrid.net in Message-ID. How do I do that? What am I doing wrong?

Would appreciate any pointers / suggestions / comments at all. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: In the email that gets rejected, is the order of the headers as you've shown, with `From:` before `Message-ID:`, _in the raw message_? Sometimes, email readers reorder the headers when displaying a message...

Comment: Yes, Kusalananda, it is the correct order of their headers. First they have From: and after it they have Message-ID: I have checked it for many times too.